# Как сделать два слова в одну строку?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как записать happy и holidays в одну строку?

Comment: Заменить обычный пробел на неразрывный. И молиться, чтобы не поделилось в другом месте...

Answer (score 1):

задать стиль блоку с текстом `white-space: nowrap`

Answer (score 0):

В CSS свойствах укажите `white-space: nowrap`. Еще больше информации про это свойсво тут: [white-space](http://htmlbook.ru/css/white-space)